# StackLayout HeightRequest/WidthRequest based on orientation

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

In a .NET MAUI App I use a CommunityToolkit Popup with a Grid or any other Layout inside.

This Layout (in code below the outer Grid) should get a HightRequest and WidthRequest based on the Orientation of the Screen so that the Content is always visible nicely and the Buttons for instance can be clicked. On the inner Grid, I also want to use other controls to select values from later on.

I could set a HeightRequest="500" and WidthRequest="300" which works well when in Portrait View, but doesn't look good when in Landscape View.

Is there a good way, I can set these Requests based on the Orientation and adapt when the View has changed?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
           xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
           xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:LocalizationResourceManager.Maui;assembly=LocalizationResourceManager.Maui"
           xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:OptimizationApp.ViewModels"
           xmlns:databaseModels="clr-namespace:OptimizationApp.DatabaseModels"
           x:DataType="viewModels:CustomPopupViewModel"
           x:Class="MacroOptimizerApp.Pages.Views.Controls.CustomPicker.CustomPopupContentPage"
           CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="False">
           
           
           
    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, Auto" Background="White">

        <SearchBar Grid.Row="0" ios:SearchBar.SearchBarStyle="Minimal" Text="{Binding SearchText}" Placeholder="{loc:Translate CustomPickerPopup_SearchPlaceholder}" Margin="0, 0, 0, 5"  />

        
        
        <!-- Cancel/OK-Button -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" RowDefinitions="35" ColumnDefinitions="Auto, Auto" ColumnSpacing="5" HorizontalOptions="End">

            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="FontAutoScalingEnabled" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="35" />
                    <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="100" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15, 7, 15, 10" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="{loc:Translate CancelButtonText}" Clicked="CancelButton_Clicked" />
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="{loc:Translate OKButtonText}" Clicked="OkButton_Clicked" Command="{Binding OkButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedValue}" />

        </Grid>
        
    </Grid>
           
           
</toolkit:Popup>
```

Comment: Set them in code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define two properties on your view model and bind them to the properties `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` of your layout.

You can refer to the following code:

1.create a view model and implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` , then add two properties `Height` and `Width`.

```
public class TestViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{

    Double _height;
    public Double Height
    {
        get => _height;
        set => SetProperty(ref _height, value);
    }

    Double _width;
    public Double Width
    {
        get => _width;
        set => SetProperty(ref _width, value);
    }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        Width = 200;
        Height = 200;
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

2.Usage example:

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

On your page, try to override method `OnSizeAllocated`, we can detect the orientation of the screen, then based on the result, we can change the value of the property that defined on the viewmodel.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{
    TestViewModel viewModel; 

    public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

        viewModel = new TestViewModel();    
        this.BindingContext = viewModel;
      }

    private double width = 0;
    private double height = 0;

    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
        //var state = (width > height) ? "Landscape" : "Portrait";

        if (width != this.width || height != this.height)
        {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            if (width > height)//Landscape
            {
                viewModel.Width = 100;
                viewModel.Height = 100;
            }
            else  //Portrait
            {
                viewModel.Width = 200;
                viewModel.Height = 200;

            }
        }
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
  <Grid  BackgroundColor="Yellow" RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, Auto"   HeightRequest="{Binding Height}" WidthRequest="{Binding Width}"  > 
       
 </Grid>
```

**Note:**

For more information, you can check document: [Device Orientation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation?tabs=windows).

Although this document is about Xamarin.Forms, it also applies to MAUI.

Comment: That's a good idea and is working good for me like this :)